# How to divide to multiple column sql?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Based on the sql result above i want to divide the result like the image below

[image]

I tried using case it return duplicate data.

Anyone have done this or have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Which database platform? MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server can have different approaches.

Comment: Looks like a `group by` would work.

Comment: @tadman sql server 2008

Comment: Tagging this with MySQL wasn't necessary then. Do try and double check those tags.

Comment: How many different values do you have to account for in `hatch_num_1`?

Comment: I think you may have to use dynamic sql query

Comment: i tried using while and it still return duplicate value

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* from yourtable WHERE t1.hatch_num_1 != t2.hatch_num_1
JOIN yourtable t2 ON t1.delay_code_1=t2.delay_code_1
```

Afterwards you can mention exactly what columns you wan't from both t1 and t2 and mention with 'as' how do you wan't them to be named in your select statement, so instead of having 2 hatch_num_1 you wil have one with _1 and one with _3

Answer (score 0):

```
;With 
a As (SELECT * FROM  yourtable X Where X.hatch= 'H1' ),
b AS (SELECT * FROM yourtable Y Where Y.hatch= 'H3')
SELECT  A.* ,B.* FROM A , B WHERE  A.[delay] = B.[delay]
```

If you have limited hatches and same time that are repeating then you can do it like this or show me some more records or details then i'll came to know...